# EventBus does not Register

Tags: android, event-bus

its work in another activity but in this activity not working and print this

error

```
 No subscribers registered for event class     com.jabizparda.salamtaxi.event.IDontWantEvent

 No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
```

register

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    presenter.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(InOutActivity.this);


 }


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    showProgress(false);
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(InOutActivity.this);
    super.onStop();

 }
```

post eventbus

```
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new IDontWantEvent("hello"));
```

method IDontWantEvent

```
 public class IDontWantEvent {
private String message;

public IDontWantEvent(String message) {
    this.message = message;


}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
}
```

subscribe

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
void iDontWantCallback(IDontWantEvent iDontWantEvent){
    showProgress(false);
}
```

please help me this issue was posted in other q but i did all work that told on past post please help me to solve it

Comment: As the error/warning says you never subscribe to those events. Add the annotation `@Subscribe`

Comment: You have registered the EventBus but have no methods with a @Subscribe  annotation.

Comment: @Kuffs   i had subscribe method but dident add in q now i updated it waht can i do?

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler   i had subscribe method but dident add in q now i updated it waht can i do?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing in the correct activity to the register method. It looks suspicious that you use InoutActivity.this instead of just "this"

Comment: it s not working with "this" i really confused there is no problem but dont work @Kuffs

Comment: Try posting a Gist on github containing your complete Activity. Maybe the error is not is the separate snippets you have posted.

Comment: i solved it, you should define subscribe method before method that use it @Kuffs